# Extracting URLs from text and using dictionary to translate face book in free text to facebook.com

Tags: regex, full-text-search, data-cleaning

I need to extract websites from text survey responses.  The algorithm should broadly match.  For example "patients like me" or "patientslikeme" should be recognized as "patientslikeme.org".

I have included responses from the data set below.  I starting writing some scripts to do this but realized I am not using a robust design pattern that will accept additional filters and dictionaries.  A simple regular expression wasn't working because the match was either too precise or too general to catch a sufficient number of matches.  In a perfect world I could also use something like [aspell](http://aspell.net/) to correct spelling mistakes or use the [levenstein](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#Computing_Levenshtein_distance) algorithm to match words.

Thanks in advance for pointing me in the direction of any data cleansing algorithms, frameworks, or resources.

> The whole beauty of "online
>   communities"is that they are, to a
>   large degree, anonymous. However:
>   Accessible Gardening Forum, 
>   Davesgarden.com; Patientslikeme.com;
>   and of course FACEBOOK.

```
$sites = array("davesgarden.com","patientslikeme.com","facebook.com");
```

> Patient Like Me  Ms Society  Facebook 
>   Thisisms

```
$sites = array("patientslikeme.com","mssociety.org","facebook.com","thisisms.com");
```

> yaoo webmd.co

```
$sites = array("yahoo.com","webmd.com");
```

> MS treatment options.com

```
$sites = array("mstreatmentoptions.com");
```

Comment: What makes those the correct sites? What about whole.com or beauty.com or onlinecommunities.com?

Comment: Good point.  I suppose we would have some knowledge of known sites and match against those.  The dataset is small enough that we could put unmatched results into a quarantine and then add those to the matching engine by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a ruby script.

Feed it a list of domains in this format, named inputfile.txt:

```
myurl.com
otherurl.com
```

Save this in a file called convert.rb

```
while line = gets
        line =~ /(.+)\.\w+$/
        print "/"
        $1.each_char{|c|
                print "#{c}\\W*"
        }
        print "/i"
        puts
end
```

Then run this command: cat inputfile.txt | ruby convert.rb > outputfile.txt

That's a list of regexes.  Take those and try to match each one on your input text.